# dynamic name in function cvSaveImage

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

i have code to input image name like IMG01.

```
 ostringstream input;
    input << z << ".jpg";
    string filename = input.str();
    const char* filename1 = filename.c_str(); [image processing here...]
```

then, i want save an image result with name bwIMG01.jpg using `cvSaveImage`. Exp:

```
cvSaveImage("bwIMG01.jpg", imgBW);
```

my problem is to write change the output name for every image. i've tried this code below, but it is not work....

```
char savedImg [30];
string savedCode = "bw";
savedImg = savedCode+filename;
cvSaveImage(savedImg, imgBiner);
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to:

```
cvSaveImage(string(savedCode+filename).c_str(), imgBiner);
```

*Suggestion*: since you're using C++, you should use the [new C++ API](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imwrite) instead, it will work directly:

```
imwrite(savedCode+filename, imgBiner);
```

Comment: thanks for your help, @herohuyongtao. That's work. May nest project i'll use new C++ API.

Answer (score 0):

please use the c++ api, and the handy cv::format() instead:

```
cv::Mat imBW;
for ( int i=0; i<30; i++ )
    imwrite( format("bwIMG%02d.jpg", i), imgBW);
```

again, please avoid the old c-api, it is no more developed.